# Error in building ct-ng in crosstool-ng-1.9.3

Tags: crosstool-ng, cloog

I'm trying to build ct-ng in crosstool-ng-1.9.3 on my 64 bit ubuntu 13.04 but I repeatedly receive the following error during this command :
`./ct-ng build`

```
[INFO ]  Retrieving needed toolchain components' tarballs
[ERROR]    Could not retrieve 'cloog-ppl-0.15.10'.
[07:00] / make: *** [build] Error 1
```

Does anyone have any clue how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing the full build.log file.
I'm going to guess and say it's failing at the point where it downloads that tar.

I would do the following (based on my assumption):
Delete the cloog-ppl-0.15.10.tar.bz stump in /some/path/.../.build/tarfiles
Download the tar manually.
You can either place the tar file in that location or in ./ct-ng menuconfig
Tell it to look at a directory locally.